# I want red borders on form submit on invalid fields using django template language

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, jinja2

This is my html file

I want red borders on form submit on invalid fields using django template language

I want red borders on form submit on invalid fields using django template language

I want red borders on form submit on invalid fields using django template language

```
{% block body %} {% include 'navbar.html'%}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <body>
       
      <form autocomplete="off" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="Title" class="form-label">Title</label>
          {{form.title}}
          <div class="form-text">{{form.title.errors}}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="Written By" class="form-label">Written by</label>
          {{form.written_by}}
          <div class="form-text">
            {{ form.written_by.errors }}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="Description" class="form-label">Description</label>
          {{form.description}}
          <div class="form-text">{{form.description.errors}}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="image" class="form-label">Image</label>
          {{form.image}}
          <div class="form-text">{{form.image.errors}}</div>
        </div>

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
       <style>

        .form-control {
          width: 50%;
        }
     

        .errorlist {
          list-style-type: none;
          color: red;
          position: relative;
          right: 31px;
          
        }
        form {
          margin-left: 30%;
          margin-right: 30%;
        }
        textarea {
          height: 4em;
          width: 50em;
        }
        
      </style>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

I want red borders on form submit on invalid fields using django template language

I want red borders on form submit on invalid fields using django template language

I want red borders on form submit on invalid fields using django template language

Comment: Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be writing the entire form fields yourself. For example, for your `{{form.title}}`, you could use:

```
<input type="text" name="{{form.title.html_name}}" id="{{form.title.id_for_label}}" class="{% if form.title.errors %}invalid-input{% endif %}">
```

Then in your styles:

```
.invalid-input {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: It works but when i submit values on form fields the values of fields are disappering from form fields.

Comment: inside your input field, add `value={{form.title.value}}`

Comment: It works and my input field would be   <input type="text" name="{{form.title.html_name}}" value="{% if form.title.value %} {{form.title.value}}{% endif %}" id="{{form.title.id_for_label}}" 
          class="{% if form.title.errors %}invalid-input{% endif %}">

Comment: Better optimal: `<input type="text" name="{{form.title.html_name}}" value="{{form.title.value|default_if_null:''}}" id="{{form.title.id_for_label}}" class="{% if form.title.errors %}invalid-input{% endif %}">`

Comment: Ok Rohit But I use:   <input type="text" class="form-control{% if form.title.errors %} invalid-input{% endif %}" name="title" value="{% if form.title.value %} {{form.title.value}} {% endif %}" 
            placeholder=" " id="id_title">